# Add new field to user info in admin account

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, adminhtml, admin-user

I need to add a custom field to the user account information while creating a user under

```
system > permission > user > add new user
```

I need to add a "location" field along with firstname, lastname, email and password fields.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

1- This tutorial may help you, it does exact the same thing you want but just for customer account [Add Custom Field to Customer Address](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address)

2- Another rough method is that you override the magento core files,

-> `app/code/core/mage/adminhtml/block/permissions/users/edit/tab/main.php`

and add your desired field
and then goto database `admin_user` table and add that field there

Comment: That is for customer address. But here I'm trying to add new field to admin user in the admin panel.

Comment: You just need to set it according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a column to the `admin_user` table.

```
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('admin/user'), 'location', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'length' => 256,
    'nullable' => true,
    'default' => null
));
```

Then, if you want to add/edit this field from the backend you need to rewrite the method `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Permissions_User_Edit_Tab_Main::_prepareForm` and add a new element in there:

```
        $fieldset->addField('location', 'select', array(
            'name'      => 'is_active',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('location'),
            'id'        => 'is_active',
            'title'     => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('location'),
            'class'     => 'input-select',
            'style'     => 'width: 80px',
            'options'   => array('1' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Yes'), '0' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('No')),
        ));
```

Clear the cache and it should work.